# Multiplying Quines

Tags: code-golf, quine, code-generation

The program should start out with 2 separate files, here named "a" and "b". "a" and "b" should be what I am calling inverse quines: "a", when run, should output "b"'s source code, and "b", when run, should output "a"'s source code, for example:

```
./a
#source code of b, optionally followed by newlines
./b
#source code of a, optionally followed by newlines
```

If the outputs of "a" and "b" are then appended to the same file, here called "c", such as this:

```
touch c
./a >> c
./b >> c
```

The resulting file, "c", when run, should output the code of "a", followed by a newline, followed by the source code of "b" and a newline. The full running of these files should go as follows:

```
touch c
./a >> c
./b >> c
./c
#source code of a \n
#source code of b \n
```

Any coding languages can be used, and as this is code golf, the source code should be as small as possible.

There are no limits on what the source code of "a" and "b" can be, and newlines can be placed freely at the end of code outputs, such that the output ends in a single or a string of newlines.

Comment: As you're new user, it's recommended that you leave the challenges in the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges - Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/) for at least 72 hours before posting it on the main site

Comment: Is it allowed that `a` and `b` are identical?

Comment: Also is it allowed if `a` alone outputs source of `b` **and a newline**, and vice versa?

Comment: Are we allowed to ignore/redirect output from stderr when running our program?

Comment: stderr should have no output, unless all output is going through stderr. Basically, only either stdout or stderr should be used.

Comment: That "new lines can be placed freely" will definitely encourage some Lenguage answers that consists of solely newlines...

Comment: I have said that newlines may be placed freely _at the end of the code sections_ not int the code sections. Sorry if this was not clear enough.

Comment: Lenguage can write programs that are entirely newlines, so newlines at the end are just as good.

Comment: Do programs have to terminate?

Comment: Yes, the programs have to terminate at some point, preferably within a minute.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, <sup>63</sup> 37 bytes

### a

```
t=;x(){ cat $2 $1;};x b \
```

### b

```
${t-cat} a
```

<sup>-26 bytes thanks to Nahuel Fouilleul</sup>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc@9CoMwEAfw/Z7ihkB0cGhXrdCChUIfwSV3plgIhmJEW/HZbVSkDnX93/3ug1RdjiMrh0kir7d7dpaYogJ3irsg7HGqiCOKQzzEHRLmMDcBbMhlIgSid5FPB6/ndOlRHqXIAJpLizLrNDdO@zhgWzldOaxL25gC9atRBimUQP4mP2QRQubVimgHqRXRH8R7CB/WGNvqAun928ubEfXzoyW0jBFPf4zjFw)

### quick explanation

There are two key tricks:

- We define our own version of `cat` called `x` which swaps its arguments, when there are 2 arguments given.  It will have only 1 argument when `a` is run, but 2 arguments when `c` is run.
- `b` uses bash default arguments to accomplish what it needs.  When `t` is undefined, as it will be when `b` is run alone, it becomes `cat a`.  When t is defined, it just returns `a`, becoming the second argument to `a` command `x b a`.

Comment: Excuse me if I am wrong, but is the first line of "a" needed? The program seems to run fine without it for me, and there is no  difference in error codes, so if it is neccecary, could someone please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: @Jake I will add a quick explanation, but without it the output of c will be wrong.

Comment: Note that this solution reads its own source code, which is not allowed under standard quine rules.

Comment: (originally there was no quine tag on the challenge but I added it because it seems relevant)

Comment: Hmm... I was going by "There are no limits on what the source code of "a" and "b" can be," but if the author deems this illegal I'll delete it or re-adapt it not to use `cat`.  Also, possibly relevant is that the programs each read each other's source code but not their own.

Comment: Seeing as these are not technically quines, although very similar, I would say that the use of `cat` is fine.

Comment: assuming the answer is valid, shortenned to 37bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc@9CoMwEAfw/Z7ihkB0cGhXrdCChUIfwSV3plgIhmJEW/HZbVSkDnX93/3ug1RdjiMrh0kir7d7dpaYogJ3irsg7HGqiCOKQzzEHRLmMDcBbMhlIgSid5FPB6/ndOlRHqXIAJpLizLrNDdO@zhgWzldOaxL25gC9atRBimUQP4mP2QRQubVimgHqRXRH8R7CB/WGNvqAun928ubEfXzoyW0jBFPf4zjFw "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thanks!  And yes, according to OP, the approach is allowed.

Comment: @Jonah, ok, even shortter removing the trailing newlines and using subshell as function body [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc@xDsIgEMbxnaf4BgztwKBrtZtv0QWuNG1CQIWmVeOzI01s1ETXy/93l9Mq9CmdLoOLHTYBIh6quSgLUhF8B74tqxkaolaMfVT8HmVOHlACNTRjS69yWIMYM9R7iONsaIwmjwvyLhoXEXo/2hbmPCoLXQqm83mol@BiL2XjVqf/OLU6/dvRP4fOW@sn00Jf39fpe0vjwnAzgk0ESctLKT0B "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 39 (20+19) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

### Program a:

```
"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrS46tPvQCjTu//8A)

### Program b:

```
"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrS46tPvQChTu//8A)

### Program c (concatenation of a+b):

```
"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrS46tPvQChK4//8DAA) or [try it online as pure quine](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydjk8PLDa1wOrS46tPvQCjQuFz5prv//AQ).

**Explanation:**

*Program a:*

```python
"34çìD«r»¨"           # Push string '34çìD«r»¨'
           34         # Push 34
             ç        # Convert it to a character: '"'
              ì       # Prepend it in front of the string: '"34çìD«r»¨'
               D      # Duplicate it
                «     # Merge the copy to itself: '"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨'
                 r    # Reverse the items on the stack
                      # (no-op, since there is just a single item)
                  »   # Join all items on the stack by newlines
                      # (no-op, since there is just a single item)
                   ¨  # Remove the last character: '"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»'
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

*Program b:*

The same as program a, but without the trailing `¨`, so it'll output `"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨` (being program a) instead.

*Program c:*

```python
"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨  # It starts the same as program a
"34çìD«r»¨"           # Push string '34çìD«r»¨'
                      #  STACK: ['"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»', '34çìD«r»¨']
           34çìD«     # Do the same as above
                      #  STACK: ['"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»', '"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨']
                 r    # Reverse the items on the stack
                      #  STACK: ['"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨', '"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»']
                  »   # Join all items on the stack by newlines
                      #  STACK: ['"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»¨\n"34çìD«r»¨"34çìD«r»']
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 60 * 2 bytes

This is essentially a quine relay but within one language. Here is `a.rb`:

```ruby
eval s=%q[1;puts "eval s=%q[#{s[0][?1]&&?2||?1}#{s[1..]}]"]
```

The `b.rb` is only different in one symbol:

```ruby
eval s=%q[2;puts "eval s=%q[#{s[0][?1]&&?2||?1}#{s[1..]}]"]
```

Testing:

```bash
$ ruby b.rb > c.rb
$ diff c.rb a.rb
$ ruby a.rb > c.rb
$ diff c.rb b.rb
$ ruby b.rb >> c.rb
$ ruby c.rb
eval s=%q[1;puts "eval s=%q[#{s[0][?1]&&?2||?1}#{s[1..]}]"]
eval s=%q[2;puts "eval s=%q[#{s[0][?1]&&?2||?1}#{s[1..]}]"]
```